# laravel upload file 0 byte on the server

Tags: php, laravel

I use below script to uploade a file to the sevre. it works fine on the local host (wamp server), but when I try to use it on the server I figure out that the uploaded file size is 0 byte.
Any one know taht where is the problem?

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request)
    {
       
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'auther_id'=>'required',

            'doc_type'=>'required',
            
           'file'=>'required|mimes:pdf'
        ]);
        
        $fileModel = new File;
    
            $fileName = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            
            $filePath = $request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
          
            $fileModel->name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
            $fileModel->save();
             
            
      
    }
```

Comment: The usual suspects are the maximum POST request size and maximum upload file size configured in the PHP settings ...

Comment: I have set the max post and upload size to 50MB, so it's not the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of this error was permissions of some folders. I just reset the host completely and now everything work like a charm.

Comment: A permission on which side, Google pixel? Or Laravel storage folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use like this. first of all you need to store your file inside storage. then you can get public url from storage.

Try this way

```
$fileName = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::put('/public/uploads/'.$fileName,$request->file('file'));
$url = Storage::url('public/uploads/'.$fileName);

$fileModel = new File;
$fileModel->name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$fileModel->file_path = $url;
$fileModel->save();
```

Comment: when I use this, I get this error:  "message": "The \"\" file does not exist or is not readable.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "/home/acaderna/public_html/vendor/symfony/mime/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php",

Comment: seems like mime type error occured. try to upload image with file type Ex: 'png'

Comment: I tried all known file types, no changes. same error

Comment: @SaeedMi check is this correct.
$request->file->getClientOriginalName()
 if you dont need actual name you can generate file name from here